# How to show sub address point of single address on google map

Tags: android, ios, google-maps

I want to show sub address point on google map of single address . Like i have latlong of airport place and i want show sub address latlong point on google map like GATE-1 of Airport and Gate-2 of Airport like this sub address latlong point ..if any one know  how to get this point ? please let me know... I'm using place api for show airport point on google map

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, information about airport gates is not exposed in Google Maps APIs. There is a feature request in Google issue tracker to add this functionality. You can see a feature request at

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68194442

Feel free to star the feature request to add your vote and subscribe to further notifications. Hopefully one day Google will implement the feature.